# URL на карту с 2 метками: как кастомизировать метки

Tags: yandex-maps-api, url

Тут описано, как создать URL на карту с 2 метками:
https://yandex.ru/dev/yandex-apps-launch/maps/doc/concepts/yandexmaps-web.html#yandexmaps-web__section_b3b_cst_ngb

Пример URL:
[https://yandex.ru/maps/?ll=30.310182,59.951059&pt=30.335429,59.944869~30.34127,59.89173&z=12&l=map](https://yandex.ru/maps/?ll=30.310182,59.951059&pt=30.335429,59.944869%7E30.34127,59.89173&z=12&l=map)

Отображается так:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Вопрос:
Возможно ли как-то пометить маркеры - к примеру, цифрами "1" и "2", или различными цветами?

Речь идет исключительно об URL-запросе.
Исходная задача:

- HomeAssistant формирует оповещение в Telegram о перемещении человека (координты исходные, координаты конечные);
- оповещение включает в себя URL (пример ссылки - выше) на карту, которая сейчас отображает 2 точки - без указания "исходная", "конечная".

Answer (score 0):

При запуске карты через URL Яндекс не предлагает вариантов кастомизировать метки. Но вы можете создать публичную страничку в сети с [JS API Яндекс Карт](https://yandex.ru/dev/maps/jsapi/doc/2.1/quick-start/index.html), которая будет передавать в скрипт карты параметры URL'а.

В параметрах вы можете транслировать координаты нужного числа меток и их свойства. А если эта страница будет публичной, никаких нарушений ПС Яндекса не будет, можно будет спокойно использовать бесплатную лицензию.

Про передачу параметров из адресной строки в javascript тут где-то уже обсуждали. Но можете и самостоятельно собрать свой алгоритм получения и обработки **window.location.search**.

Comment: Спасибо за обстоятельный ответ! К сожалению, это слишком сложно для моей задачи. Мне всего лишь нужно отображать 2 точки и как-то их различать. Я могу альтернативно использовать static-maps (в запросе можно добавить 2 точки, указать их названия и даже соединить их линией - тогда видно перемещение "откуда - куда"); но хотелось это сделать именно в нормальных картах, а не на статичной картинке

Comment: Должен заметить тогда, что таким подходом вы будете нарушать ПС Яндекса – даже статичная карта должна отображаться на публичном сайте, а не открываться одним пустым запросом лично для вас.

Comment: Я далек от использования Я-сервисов как разработчик и плохо понял, что вы мне написали. Итого я передаю в составе сообщения ТМ только:
1. Ссылку на карту с 2мя добавл. точками (откуда-куда) с центрированием между точками (вычисляю центр) и автозумом (вычисляю исходя из расст. между точками).
2. Статичную картинку (static-maps) с теми же 2мя точками, соед. линией и метками "1" и "2".
Получив сообщение, я на картинке увижу перемещение человека, подроб. инфу могу получить по ссылке на карту.
Глуб. изучение Я-сервисов не входило в планы, у меня искл. настройка умного дома.
Спасибо за помощь!